Spring-kafka - Docker-compose [WINDOWS]
Using this docker-compose file:
version: '3.6'
services:
  akhq:

    image: tchiotludo/akhq
    environment:
      AKHQ_CONFIGURATION: |
        micronaut:
          server:
            port: 9080
        akhq:
          connections:
            docker-kafka-server:
              properties:
                bootstrap.servers: "kafka:29092"
    

    ports:
      - "9080:9080"
    links:
      - kafka


  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper

    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: '2181'
      ZOOKEEPER_ADMIN_ENABLE_SERVER: 'false'

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '0'
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: '12'
      KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE: 'gzip'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: '1'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: '9091'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: 'kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer'
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
    links:
      - zookeeper

When I launch Spring boot application (using spring-kafka dependency),
the first time It works and create the topics, after few seconds, I get infinity of logs like:
2024-04-08T16:44:43.242+02:00  WARN 13712 --- [my_ms] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my_ms-group-1, groupId=my_ms-group] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-04-08T16:45:05.148+02:00  INFO 13712 --- [my_ms] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my_ms-group-1, groupId=my_ms-group] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-04-08T16:45:05.148+02:00  INFO 13712 --- [my_ms] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my_ms-group-1, groupId=my_ms-group] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 70 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 21051ms, elapsed time since send: 21051ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
